# How to disable horizontal scrolling in ScrollBar (JavaFX)?

Tags: javafx, horizontal-scrolling, mousewheel

I disabled showing the horizontal ScrollBar with following code:

```
scrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
```

It's no longer visible, but usuable with the mouse wheel. How can I prevent that?

There's a ScrollPane with vertical ScrollBar. But I can click the mouse wheel to right and the content is scrolling horizontal.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Do you want the scrollpane height to fit its content height ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT: Use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30392217/1594933) instead of this hacky one**

---

You could consume the horizontal [`ScrollEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/ScrollEvent.html) in an [event filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/filters.htm):

```
    scrollPane.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.SCROLL,new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {
            if (event.getDeltaX() != 0) {
                event.consume();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: this is such an ugly hack, i cant even! It has so many unwanted sideeffects.. please use the solution further below using setFitToWidth(true)!

Answer (score 49):

`scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);`

Comment: how do i apply this method to listviwe or jfxlistviwe?

Answer (score 6):

I believe this is the proper way:

```
sp.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
```